# What are the differences in sweeping between the two sweepers in the curling?

Tags: technique, tactics, curling

Mainly the skip asks the sweepers do both sweep actions, but sometimes the skip asks a single player to do action.

What is the difference between the sweeping to choose one rather than another sweeper?

Answer (score 2):

It's affecting the curl of the stone.

- One sweeper enhances the curl away from the sweeper.
- A second sweeper on the other side of the stone would cause the same effect in the opposite direction, which would cancel or reduce the curl (depending on who sweeps more/better).

So depending on who sweeps (or sweeps more than the other sweeper) you can basically steer the stone by giving it more or less curl... so if you need a lot of curling only one sweeper takes action until the stone is on its designated track, while with two sweepers working equally the stone just goes more straight forward.